# The product of a fundamental matrix and constant matrix is not a solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, determinant, fundamental-solution

Let $C$ constant matrix and $\Phi$ a fundamental matrix, i need to show that $C\Phi$ is not necesary a solution for the equation $y'=Ay$. I think the solution follows from seeing that the determinant of C can be 0 and that give a problem, but i dont see, any hint? thanks!

Comment: Just write the condition for $\Psi(t) = C\Phi(t)$ to be a solution of $\dot{\Psi} = A \Psi$.

Comment: Thanks! this hint was very helpful!